# Отправка первого кадра видер

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg

На сервере лежит куча видео файлов с камер видеонаблюдения, есть необходимость отдавать первый кадр видео по запросу от клиента. Скажем пришел get-запрос 01-01-2021.jpg, мы ищем это видео в папке и командой ffmpeg -i /records/01-01-2021.mp4 -vframe 1 возвращаем кадр с нужного видео.
Подскажите, как такое реализовать с помощью nginx?

Comment: Сгенерируйте jpg-файлы заранее и просто настройте раздачу статических файлов?

Comment: Зачем лишние движения? Проще по запросу это сделать... тем более происходит ротация видео, большинство jpg не понадобятся